# How to create an update-able, ordered list structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, querying

I'm trying to create an web-app that has an card-like interface for drag and dropping documents within a container (similar to a "Asana Dashboard").

[image: Asana dashboard example]

The problem I'm facing is that I can't figure out an efficient way to store this data in a structured and easily update-able manner. I had a look at a linked-list-like structure before but it was a nightmare to query. The solution I'm currently using is based on a extra position column that is recalculated on each insert/update/delete but this solution is gets quite slow on big lists:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS section (
    id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    collection_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    position SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE INDEX section_position (collection_id, position)
);

INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("0", 0, "1", "Test 1");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("1", 1, "1", "Test 2");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("2", 2, "1", "Test 3");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("3", 3, "1", "Test 4");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("4", 4, "1", "Test 5");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("5", 5, "1", "Test 6");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("6", 6, "1", "Test 7");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("7", 7, "1", "Test 8");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("8", 8, "1", "Test 9");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("9", 9, "1", "Test 10");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("a", 10, "1", "Test 11");
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("b", 11, "1", "Test 12");

-- Insert
SET @maxPos=(SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM section WHERE collection_id="1");
UPDATE section SET position=position+1 WHERE collection_id="1" AND position>=0 ORDER BY position DESC;
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("13", IF(@maxPos<0, @maxPos, 0), "1", "Insert Test 1");

-- Remove
SET @oldPos=(SELECT position FROM section WHERE id="6");
DELETE FROM section WHERE id="6";
UPDATE section SET position=position-1 WHERE collection_id="1" AND position>=@oldPos ORDER BY position ASC;

-- Update
SET @maxPos=(SELECT MAX(position) FROM section WHERE collection_id="1");
SET @newPos=IF(@maxPos<10, @maxPos, 10);
SET @oldPos=(SELECT position FROM section WHERE id="2");
SET @shiftingDirection=IF(@oldPos>@newPos, 1, -1);

DELETE FROM section WHERE id="2";
UPDATE section SET position=position+@shiftingDirection WHERE collection_id="1" AND position BETWEEN @oldPos AND @newPos ORDER BY position-IF(@shiftingDirection=1, 0, @maxPos);
INSERT INTO section (id, position, collection_id, title) VALUES ("2", @newPos, "1", "Test 2");
```

Is there another, more efficient way of storing data that is structured like this and if so is there a way to automate the list management with stuff like triggers?

Regards

BitPhinix

Comment: Lowest position is top-right in the UI? Inserting a new section always takes top-right position? Are there any other assumptions here? I think the structure you are using is fine for storage, but I feel like most of the CRUD steps can be done in a single SQL trip (depending on how much you want back from the DB, although you should already know whats there and what will be after that one trip).

Comment: I would just study any (preferably newish) tutorial on the subject

Comment: Don't encode your state as a linked list then represent the linked list relationally; just represent the state relationally: a thing's id & its ordinal position. There are many idioms for more complex relational encodings with various tradeoffs, but they are based on how DBMSs work; your encoding as linked list isn't so based. PS Tables have no order, result sets [sic] have order. What do you think the order bys are doing?

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: First of thanks for the answers but I woudn't have asked if I found a solution for it online ... And trust me I googled for hours!